# $group in Mogoose Random Results But No Duplicate in Pagination

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Actually i want to produce random results each time page loads, it's working but on pagination sometimes I got
duplicate results one or two products, am i doing something wrong. i am randomising by spliting product_code. your
help is really appreciated.

```
var obj = {
  $or: [
    {
      'main_data.product_name': {
        $regex: req.body.searchTerm,
        $options: 'i'
      }
    },
    {
      'main_data.product_code': {
        $regex: req.body.searchTerm,
        $options: 'i'
      }
    }
  ],
'main_data.status': 'active',
}

var query = [
{ $unwind: '$main_material' },
{
  $project: {
    product_name: 1,
    product_code: 1,
    main_material: 1,
    status:1,
    qty_per_box:1,
    city_state: { $split: ["$product_code", "-"] },
    qty: 1
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    product_name: 1,
    product_code: 1,
    main_material: 1,
    status:1,
    qty_per_box:1,
    city_state: "$city_state"
  }
},
{ $group: { _id: { "pc": "$city_state" }, main_data: { "$first": "$$ROOT" }, cdate: { "$first": "$createdOn" } } }, 
{ $match: obj}, 
{ $sort: { "price_usd": 1 } },
{ $skip: parseInt(req.params.skip) },
{ $limit: parseInt(req.body.items) },
]  
Products_model.aggregate(query);

My Exact requirement is to show random products every time. But due to random list in
pagination it creates duplicity in the results.
```

Comment: Which part exactly makes it random?

Comment: $group is making random results as i am not sorting on main_data